# Google Spreadsheets sum or rows of certain columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Google Spreadsheets syntax, so forgive me if this sounds too trivial. :)

I want to sum up the row values of certain columns in my Google Spreadsheets sheet into a new column.

I'm looking for the right command to do this.

What I've stumbled upon till now is the sum function =SUM(A1:F1) --- to sum up the row values of column A up to column F for the first row. However, I only want to sum up certain columns --- i.e. only the row values of B and D for instance.

**Minimal Working Example**

```
     | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Sum B + D |
     |----------|----------|----------|----------|-----------|
Row 1| a1       | b1       | c1       | d1       | b1 + d1   |
Row 2| a2       | b2       | c2       | d2       | b2 + d2   |
Row 3| a3       | b3       | c3       | d3       | b3 + d3   |
```

I want to construct the last column (Sum B + D) with a spreadsheet formula.

[image]

Comment: I can help. Do you want add A, D, E in each row and show in your Sum column?

Comment: Like in my MWE, I want to add, for instance, column B and D and make a new column out of these computed values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Step 1: Double click on the cell where you want to insert the formula.

[image]

> Step 2: Bring the mouse pointer to the highlighted area as shown in below image till you see a '+' sign.

[image]

Step 3: how to apply formula to entire column?

- **Method 1:** Click and drag till the where you need the formula to be applied.
- **Method 2:** Double click on bottom right hand corner of the cell. The formula will be applied to all occupied cells as you mentioned.
- **Edit (for Google Spreadsheets). Method 2:** Double click on bottom right hand corner of the cell *AND* drag it down up to the row to which you want to have it applied; when all rows are selected release to apply. The formula will be applied to all occupied cells as you mentioned.

Comment: Can't one write a simple macro for this? I mean, I want to add up a few rows from certain columns; is this that complex? The reason being that I have loads of rows; it's infeasible to click on each cell manually.

Comment: @Musse Redi Dont click on each cell. Just double click on bottom right hand corner of the cell where you have applied the formula. When you double click the formula gets applied to the cells below the same column.

Comment: I've tried applying method 2, as you mentioned. The cells below, however, still have the same previously assigned sum; and not the new one which I applied to the first cell of which I'm clicking the bottom right corner.

Comment: Only the formula gets copied not the previously assigned sum. Guess you are doing it wrong.. Does Column B and Column D have valid values?

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: where are rest of the columns? By the screenshot I can understand that you are adding Amount1 to Amount6..

Comment: The rest of the column are seen when scrolling to the left. But never mind; you're solution worked with a slight tweak; see my edit to your post. :)

Comment: Glad I could help.. Please do accept the answer if you are satisfied with it!

Answer (score 0):

Click the cell where you want to put the sum and simply do =SUM(B:B,D:D) for a grand total sum of all of B and all of D.

If you don't want to include top row headers, do =SUM(B2:B,D2:D)

If you want to do certain range in each row, define that range in the SUM like so:
=SUM(B4:B12,D2:D6). This will sum all values in Column B from rows 4 to 12 with all values in Column D from rows 2 to 6.

Most importantly, your example was correct. Only thing you really need to do is add a "=" in front of your own formula and hit enter. Google sheets will even capitalize your letters for you.

You can click the bottom right corner and drag that formula down through the column, but Google Sheets will likely prompt you first to autofill it anyway.